# How to list down the full paths to all files in multiple directories of a certain file format?

Tags: linux, file, path, directory, ls

I am looking for a Bash solution to my dilemma here. I have directory `project`, and within that I have `project/Batch1` `project/Batch2` `project/Batch3` and so on.

Within each Batch folder, I have a mix of files but what I am interested in are files in the .txt format, for example. I am able to recursively acquire the names of every file in my `project` directory using the `ls -LR` command. However, how should I get full paths including the file names, and also only for .txt files?

Thanks!

Comment: [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find` command. Open `man 1 find` and check possible option you need for above task.

Here is the simple example. Open terminal and run

`find pwd  -type  f  -name  "*.txt"`

Or

`find pwd  -name  "*.txt"`

Or you can do same using bash script also.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed, just had to add backticks to `pwd` for it to work.